Stochastic gradient descent with momentum: eigenvalues
I am reading the article "How Momentum really works" (https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/), and i am confused in particularly one point:
I am trying to derive the convergence rate for momentum from the equation:

$\min_{\alpha, \beta}\max\lbrace \parallel \begin{pmatrix}
   \beta & \lambda_1 \\
   -\alpha\beta & 1-\alpha\lambda_1
  \end{pmatrix}   \parallel, ..., \parallel \begin{pmatrix}
  \beta & \lambda_n \\
  -\alpha\beta & 1-\alpha\lambda_n
  \end{pmatrix}   \parallel  \rbrace$

$\parallel\parallel$ here denotes the magnitude of the maximum eigenvalue, and occurs when the roots of the characteristic polynomial are repeated for the matrices corresponding to the extremal eigenvalues. So we know that we have the eigenvalues for R:
$\sigma_i =\frac{1}{2}(1-\alpha\lambda+\beta\pm\sqrt{(-\alpha\lambda+\beta+1)^2-4\beta})$
But somehow i do not figure out how to make the algebra here. Could anyone help?
